# **mongoose save method returning an error with this message "favouriteDish.save" is not a function**

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I get an error while trying to save a document into MongoDB database collection with mongoose save method but I could not proceed to save the document because of this error `favouriteDish.save() is not a function`

I don't know if my syntax is ok. The idea is to add the favourite dish `ObjectId` to the dishes array so that the `ObjectId` pointers can be used to `populate` the document.

the mongoose schema:

```js
const favouriteDishSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  dishes: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Dish'
  }]
}, {
  timestamps: true
});
```

the file throwing the error:

```js
    .post(cors.corsWithOptions, authenticate.verifyUser, (req, res, next) => {
      Dishes.findById(req.params.favouriteDishID, (err, dish) => {
        if (err)
          return next(err);

        FavouriteDishes.find({}, (err, favouriteDish) => {

          if (favouriteDish.length <= 0) {
            FavouriteDishes.create({ user: req.user._id })
              .then((favouriteDish) => {
                if (favouriteDish.dishes.indexOf(dish._id) == -1) {
                  favouriteDish.dishes.push(dish._id);
                  favouriteDish.save()
                    .then((favouriteDish) => {
                      res.statusCode = 200;
                      res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                      res.json(favouriteDish);
                    }, (err) => next(err))
                    .catch((err) => next(err));
                }
              });
          }
          else {
            if (favouriteDish[0].dishes.indexOf(dish._id) < 0) {
              favouriteDish[0].dishes.push(dish._id);
              favouriteDish.save()  //save method throwing the error
                .then((favouriteDish) => {
                  res.statusCode = 200;
                  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                  res.json(favouriteDish);
                }, (err) => next(err))
                .catch((err) => next(err));
            }
            else {
              let err = new Error('Favourite dish(s) already exist make another choice!');
              err.status = 409;
              return next(err);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to save what is not a single `favoriteDish`. `find` [returns](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) an array of results, so in order to save the first one (that you already modified), try using `favouriteDish[0].save()` instead.

If you're always modifying only the first result, consider using [findOne](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOne) instead, so you get the first match and don't have to select from an array.

Comment: Thanks @Magnus also since i'm modifying only the first result using  findOne seems to be the best solution here.